# Self-stopping a fast-cgi application on Apache

Tags: perl, apache, fastcgi

I'm debugging a problem with Apache, Fast-CGI and our Perl application.
The root cause is that the Perl application needs to exit and be reloaded if a certain operation was done. 
Under CGI it is not a problem, as the application is being loaded for every request.

However, it seen that the Fast CGI protocol did not considered this case - there is not way to signal the WebServer that you are going to exit - you just exit.

But doing so, we ran into what seemed like a race condition on the mod_fastcgi side: it recognize that the programed exited, but then tries to send it requests. eventually it gives up and return error 500 to the browser.

I see similar error messages on the web, but these are about PHP exiting after 500 requests, and the solution is to tell fastcgi to limit requests-per-process to 500. This does not fit my problem, as I need to exit on certain request and not after fixed number of requests.

Info:
Apache module loading:

```
LoadModule fastcgi_module libexec/apache2/mod_fastcgi.so
```

Two log lines: the server detects that the app exited, but then trying to connect it

```
[Thu Jul 05 15:02:32 2012] [warn] FastCGI: (dynamic) server "/Users/sfomberg/Sites/cgi-bin/mt/mt.cgi" (pid 9277) terminated by calling exit with status '0'
[Thu Jul 05 15:02:32 2012] [warn] FastCGI: (dynamic) server "/Users/sfomberg/Sites/cgi-bin/mt/mt.cgi" has failed to remain running for 30 seconds given 3 attempts, its restart interval has been backed off to 600 seconds
```

Finally, giving up:

```
[Thu Jul 05 15:03:07 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] FastCGI: comm with (dynamic) server "/Users/sfomberg/Sites/cgi-bin/mt/mt.cgi" aborted: (first read) idle timeout (30 sec), referer: http://localhost/~sfomberg/cgi-bin/mt/mt.cgi?__mode=cfg_plugins&blog_id=0&switched=1
[Thu Jul 05 15:03:07 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] FastCGI: incomplete headers (0 bytes) received from server "/Users/sfomberg/Sites/cgi-bin/mt/mt.cgi", referer: http://localhost/~sfomberg/cgi-bin/mt/mt.cgi?__mode=cfg_plugins&blog_id=0&switched=1
```

I tried to close the listening socket directly before ending the request, (the listening socket is fileno 0) but that didn't work.

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was because mod_fastcgi was of an old version - 2.4.2
upgrading to 2.4.6 solved it.

Also, mod_fcgid does not have this problem.